# How to enter new line to html with Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that opens an IE browser and fill a form.
I also have an csv file with phone numbers. how can I insert **each phone number** **to new line** on the value tag?

tried already:

```
$phoneBox = $IE.Document.getElementById($phonesID)
$phones = Get-Content -Path "c:\phones.csv"
foreach($p in $phones)
{
   $phoneBox.value += "<br>" + $p + "<\br>" 
}
```

and also:

```
$phoneBox = $IE.Document.getElementById($phoneID)
$phones = Get-Content -Path "c:\phones.csv"
foreach($p in $phones)
{
   $phoneBox.value += $p + "\n" 
}
```

and also:

```
$phoneBox = $IE.Document.getElementById($phoneID)
$phones = Get-Content -Path "c:\phones.csv"
foreach($p in $phones)
{
   $phoneBox.value += $p + "&#13;" + "&#10;" 
}
```

EDIT:

The Html element I AM REFERING TO IS:

```
<textarea name="ctl00$MainContent$reciSel$TabsContacts$tabFromFile$txtFromFile" tabIndex="0" id="ctl00_MainContent_reciSel_TabsContacts_tabFromFile_txtFromFile" style="width: 98%; height: 386px; overflow-x: hidden;" onkeyup="PhoneNumbersTxt_onChange(this.value);" onkeypress="AddNewLine(this,event);" rows="2" cols="20" wrap="off" autocomplete="off">Here I need to enter each number to new line</textarea>
```

Comment: Assuming this is a text box (i.e. you're editing an editable field; not the HTML) my guess would be `"\`n"` (backtick + n); i.e. as in PowerShell a line break character is "`n" rather than "\n".

Comment: @JohnLBevan it's afield I can edit because i can Enter the phones to the text but are all on the same line. I each pne on new line

Comment: @JohnLBevan tried your suggestion. did not work either.

Comment: If you need a carriage return, use     `r. For a carriage return and a new line, use `r`n

Comment: Maybe `"\`r\`n"`; i.e. windows line endings?  Sorry, not something I've played with personally...

Comment: @JohnLBevan THANKS! "`r`n"works great!!

Comment: That's what I was trying to add, but failed with escaping the backticks so my comment looks a mess!

Comment: @JamesC.sorry, hadn't seen your comment when posting mine.  FYI: You can escape backticks in SO comments using backslash.  i.e. to write `"\`r\`n"` you should put `\`"\\`r\\`n"\``.

Answer (score 1):

Literal whitespace is not parsed as formatting information in HTML (all consecutive whitespace is collapsed to a single space in the output).

Either put each phone number in a separate paragraph

```
$phoneBox.value += '<p>' + $p + '</p>'
```

or (if you want it in a single block element with a linebreak after each entry) put a single `<br>` (or `<br/>` if you want valid XHTML) after the number:

```
$phoneBox.value += $p + '<br>'
```

That does not apply to the content of textareas, though. For those you add linebreaks like this (LF only):

```
$phoneBox.value += $p + "`n"
```

or like this (CR-LF):

```
$phoneBox.value += $p + "`r`n"
```

PowerShell escape sequences start with a backtick, not a backslash.

Comment: thanks for the answer. This answer correct but I already uset the suggestion from @JohnLBevan.

Comment: I know. I changed my answer to a wiki answer because he posted the solution first.

Comment: Thanks both.  Happy for @AnsgarWiechers' answer to be marked as correct; he's put more detail here than my guesswork in the comments, and it'll be helpful for anyone searching for this in future.